# C++ alternative algorithm for solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need some help with an algorithm, I have a problem with an program.
I need to make a program where user inputs cordinates for 3 points and coefficient
for linear funciton that crosses the triangle made by those 3 points and i need to compare area of the shapes what is made function crossing that triangle.

I would paste code here but there is things in my native language and i just want to know your alogrithms for this solution, becuase my wokrs only if the points are entered in exact sequence and I cant get handle of that

http://pastebin.com/vNzGuqX4 - code

and for example i use this http://goo.gl/j18Ch0
The code is not finnished, I just noticed if I enter it in different sequence it does not work like when entering points " 1 1 2 5 4 4 0.5 1 5 " works but " 4 4 1 1 2 5 0.5 1 5 " does not

Comment: No problem, paste the code here and translate variable names.

Comment: No problem with the language. We all read C++ well and speak it fluently :) Please tell us what did you try so far.

Comment: What is "coefficient for linear function"?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal That'd be `k`, I guess. `y = kx + n`.

Comment: yeah k but in this problem linear funciton is given in a form of ax+by=c, i will paste my code then

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, or more commonly y = mx + b where m is the slope. It could be, and would be more interesting if it were, a co. of regression.

Comment: @jrok Then what would be the area of shapes made by this function crossing the triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear must cross with 2 edges of the triangle at least. So you can find these 2 crossing points first, these 2 points with one of the 3 vertices will make a small triangle. Use this equation to calculate the area of a triangle S = sqrt(l * (l-a) * (l-b) * (l-c)) where l = (a+b+c)/2 and a, b, c are the length of the edge. It should be easy to get the length of an edge given the coordinate of the vertex. One is the area of the small triangle, the other one is the area of the big triangle minus the small one.

Comment: It can also cross through a vertex and then one area is 0 and the other equals the area of triangle.

Comment: @jrok yeah, it will be the special case where the area of the small triagnle equals 0.

Comment: nice!!! you just helped me with one of the problems, I did not think of subtracting small triangle from the big. I did calculate the small and then i divided the tetragon in two triangles got their area and sumed them together, but that is not the only problem wiht my solution
if i could i would upvote, but my reputation dont allow that :(

Comment: @eLbor It think the core of this problem is to find the crossing point between a segment and a line. It should be divided into 2 steps(2 subroutines maybe ), first you want to find the crossing point between 2 lines. then you check whether the point is within the segment.

Comment: @notbad yes that is the main problem, I did find the crossing, I just dont know how to check whether the point is within the segment correctly, I did it in that way that it just does it write if the A point is the lowest... basicly as its shown in the goo.gl link

Comment: @eLbor One easy way to check whether a point C is within the segment AB is to calculate the length of segment AC, BC, AB and then you check whether |AB|=|BC|+|AC|

Comment: @notbad I didnt not quite catch the idea, to chekc if we are still on the same page - How to correctly check whether the point crossing where two linear functions cross if that point is in between two other points... something like that

Comment: @eLbor Suppose that C is the crossing point and it will be on the line AB. Then if C is out of the segment AB. At least one the the segments AC, BC will be longer than the segment AB. And the equation |AB|=|BC|+|AC| holds iff C in between A and B.

Comment: @notbad oh, now I understand okay, will try and I will get back at you if something else is wrong, will accept answear when im finnished, ok? :)

Comment: @notbad i cant compare the AC+BC=AB because i can't compare double values

Comment: @eLbor Maybe you needn't compare AC+BC with AB. Just check whether |AC|^2 or |BC|^2 is larger than |AB|^2. It doesn't involve any double arithmetic.

Comment: @notbad but even if one of them is not larger it does not work e.g. 3 4 and 5 3^2=9 4^2=16 5^2=25 but 3+4 is not 5 but the square is not larger

Comment: @eLbor That is impossible, because they are collinear. if C is out of the segment AB, at least one the the segments AC, BC will be longer than the segment AB. else AC + BC = AB.

Comment: can we move to IM please? because I'm confused, but willing to learn

Comment: @notbad anyway what you was saying is that sum only can be larger if its less or equal its in the segment right? ( less is because of the precision of the double type and functions returing floating decimal point)

Answer (score 0):

If your triangle is ABC, a good approach would be the following:

- Find lines that go through points A and B, B and C, and C and A.
- Find the intersection of your line with these three lines.
- Check which two intersections lie on the triangle sides.
- Depending on the intersections calculate the surface of the new small
  triangle.